# SQL Function has no destination when called

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm getting a success when creating the below function, but when I call it I receive an error stating there is no destination.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_top_films() RETURNS int 
language PLPGSQL
AS $$
DECLARE top_films integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT i.film_id,
    COUNT(*)
    FROM rental r
        JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id=i.inventory_id
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 10;
RETURN top_films;
END;
$$
```

Comment: Your function never assigns `top_films`.

Comment: Your function is named `get_top_films`, which implies it returns a table/array/resultset, but it has `RETURNS int`, so it's a scalar function, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Very new to functions, so I'm a little confused here. My intention is to have a list of 10 film ids come back when calling the function. How else would I assign top films? I tried using it within the in the first line and after the end but it yields the same error.

Comment: Remove the `COUNT(*)` from the `SELECT` list and place `RETURN QUERY` above the query. Trash the `top_films` variable.

Comment: @JSpratt [The guide on inlining functions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) says to inline that the function it must be either `RETURNS SETOF` or `RETURNS TABLE`, which confuses me because you'd think `RETURN QUERY` would mean it's inlinable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_top_films() RETURNS setof inventory.filmid%type
language sql
AS $$
    SELECT i.film_id
    FROM rental r
        JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id=i.inventory_id
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 10
$$;
```

Language SQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html
language plpgsql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html
Language sql is more easier to understand. your query is not dynamic, so it's just a function and  $$ query $$.
`setof inventory.filmid%type` will make it more flexiable. If you filmid type change, this function no need to change.

Comment: follow this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:939860+[postgresql]

Answer (score 1):

To extend on my comment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_top_films()
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER -- or inventory.filmid%TYPE
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT i.film_id
      FROM rental r
      JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
     GROUP BY i.film_id
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
     LIMIT 10
    ;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: How does `RETURNS SETOF integer` compare to, say, `RETURNS TABLE ( filmid integer )` or `RETURN QUERY`?

Comment: @Dai I think the important thing to note is that if you `RETURN SETOF RECORD` or some unknown data structure, Postgres doesn't know the types so it would require a column definition at return time. `SETOF` is proper when you have user defined types with multiple fields or just a set of one data type.

Comment: For example, if you had `RETURN QUERY SELECT id, name ...` returning from your function, you would have to call it like `SELECT function() AS (id INTEGER, name TEXT)`.

Comment: That seems odd - so when using `RETURN QUERY` it isn't self-describing and the caller has to define the schema?

Comment: You could however create a type: `CREATE TYPE your_type AS (id INTEGER, name TEXT);` and then use `RETURNS SETOF your_type`.

Comment: It is self-describing if the return is one data type like in this question or if you return a user-defined type. You wouldn't want to use it for an undefined multi column return. `RETURNS SETOF <some_user_defined_type>` becomes really handy if you're using the same data structure to return in many different function defs. Then if you want to change the return structure for all of those functions, you only change the type definition.

Comment: That's disappointing then, because in SQL Server (my current bread-and-butter) table-valued functions are self-describing there, whereas usually SQL Server trails behind PostgreSQL for things like that...

Comment: Postgres has `RETURNS TABLE` also.